# Cross account lambda configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am attempting to run a lambda from my account against an instance in another account.  To give some background, I am attempting to collect a forensic memory sample from another account's instance and have the sample sent to S3 bucket.  I am to the point of having a working lambda to perform these forensic actions within my account against an instance in my account.  I just need some assistance on what I need to do in order to run this lambda against any other account in my org.

So far, I have created an "originRole" that includes the sts:AssumeRole that points to the MemoryRole resource as shown below.  I have left the trust relationship for this role to lambda.amazonaws.com.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/MemoryRole"
    }
]}
```

I also have the MemoryRole which includes the SSM, EC2, and S3 api call functionalities that the lambda relies on.  I have changed the MemoryRole trust relationship to:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*mysourceAccount#*:role/originRole"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then changed the Memory Lambda configuration to be run with the originRole.

I'm wondering if all of the above is correct and would appreciate any input!  Next, I am starting to work with the memory lambda to get the lambda to work properly.  Below is the code I have added that I have found in bits of documentation while I have been researching this.  I am unsure exactly what needs to be done to this code to intake an instance ID, find the account it is in and then utilize this information to perform the collection.  I feel like I am pretty close, but would like the input from some lambda experts out there to ensure I'm doing this properly! Thank you!

```
    import json
    import boto3
    import boto3.session
    import time
    import logging
    import sys
    import traceback
    import re
    from datetime import datetime
    import time
    
    
    ''' Set up a logger '''
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    identity = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()
    local_account = identity.get('Account')
    
    session_name = identity.get('Arn').split('/')[-1]
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    arn_prefix = "arn:aws:iam:"
    arn_suffix = "/".join( [ "role", identity.get('Arn').split('/')[-2] ])
    ec2client = session.client('ec2')
    arn = ':'.join([arn_prefix, instance_account, arn_suffix])
    
    
    def assume_remote_role(account, session):
        client = session.client('sts')
        credentials = client.assume_role( RoleArn = ":".join( [arn_prefix, account, arn_suffix ] ), RoleSessionName = session_name  )['Credentials']
        return boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken'])
        
        
    def lambda_handler(event, context): 
...REST OF CODE...
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Is it regarding the cross-account AssumeRole, or how to get from an Instance ID to an Account ID?

Comment: Yes to both. Just looking for some assistance on the cross account stuff as I'm not sure if I have it set up properly as well as how we can get an account # from the instance id.

Comment: You can't get an Account ID from an Instance ID. Not sure what you're trying to do in the Lambda function -- it looks like it is creating an ARN for an IAM Role in a desired account, which you'll then use to access that Account? Does it work as desired? If so, great!